My app is getting a "Install .NET 8 runtime" prompt with no changes at all in the code
I have this WinUI app published in the Microsoft Store, all good until I updated to a new version recently and, on my test device, the system shows a dialog asking to Install .NET 8 runtime in order to run the app.
The funny part is that I didn't change any target framework from the previous release, and the app was already running in that device targeting .NET 8. I even went back and created a build from the same commit I created the previous (working) release, and the prompt is still there.
Maybe I'm missing something obvious, maybe there's some issues when packaging my app locally, in any of those cases, I don't know what to check.
Thanks in advance

You mentioned that the previous version app that targets .NET 8 was running but just to be sure, what happens if you reinstall that previous version on the test device? Also, can you run "dotnet --list-runtimes" and verify that .NET 8 is installed on the test device?

Could you please tell us is your app packaged or unpackaged? If your app is unpackaged, have you set WindowsAppSDKSelfContained to true? And what you updated to the new version?

Hey. Yes, WindowsAppSDKSelfContained is set to true:

Also getting this, although it's when we've upgraded to .NET 8 from .NET 7

Here's a GitHub issue for it: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19763 - reviewing the solution now.

This is what worked for me. I added these tags to the app's .csproj and the package seems to contain the necessary runtimes:
<RuntimeIdentifier>win10-$(Platform)</RuntimeIdentifier>
<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
<IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>

Here's the source of my solution: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/3911

I just had to add SelfContained true
